# Angular String Interpolation - styling part of a string

Tags: html, angular, string-interpolation

I would like to know if it's possible to render part of a string differently in an Angular string interpolation.

I have a texts.json file with the following value:

```
"title": "Place your {{specimen_type}} here"
```

The `specimen` is a variable in the component.

In the HTML template, I have:

```
<p> {{'title' | specimen_type: specimen?.specimen_type}} </p>
```

In other words, I am substituting the placeholder `specimen_type` with the value of `specimen` in the component.

The result is properly displayed without any issues.

**However, I wonder if I can make the value of `specimen` italicized in the HTML template without breaking up the `title` in the json file.**

I've tried placing italize tags in various places, but they seem to cause the pipes to not work.

If all else fails and I have to split the string into three parts, which tag should I be using - I tried div tags but the contents become different lines - I suspect that I need to do some string concatenation, but that most likely will lose the styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered doing this inside your specimen_type pipe?

Something like this

```
@Pipe({ name: 'specimen', standalone: true })
export class SpecimenPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(
    value: string,
    placeholder: string,
    classes: string[] = []
  ): string {
    if (!value) {
      return '';
    }

    const spanClasses = classes.join(' ');
    const replacedValue = value.replace(
      `{{specimen_type}}`,
      `<span class="${spanClasses}">${placeholder}</span>`
    );

    return replacedValue;
  }
}
```

This would create a separate span element for the specimen type, allowing you to style that element via globally available classes.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6pter3?file=src/main.ts